# Axis 1.4 to 1.6.2

Tags: java, ant, apache-axis

i was migrating project from axis2 1.4 to axis2 1.6.2 and my ant scripts are not working now, i'm not good at ant scripts so im asking you

```
<taskdef name="osql"
        classname="OSqlTask"
        classpath="${build.ant.dir}"/>
    <taskdef name="finddbpatches"
        classname="FindDBPatchesTask"
        classpath="${build.ant.dir}"/>
    <taskdef resource="axis-tasks.properties"
        classpathref="ant.cp"/>
```

this yells at me that it cannot find those tasks, but if i switch back old libraries axis-1.4.jar <-> axis-1.6.2.jar it works. I was unable to find proper way to change it. Can anyone help?

//edit

taskdef class OSqlTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

taskdef class FindDBPatchesTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

askdef A class needed by class org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask cannot be found: org/apache/
 axis/utils/DefaultAuthenticator using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Comment: does ${build.ant.dir} really point to where the *.class files are located?

Comment: yes it does, as i said it was working with axis2 1.4, classes for those tasks are where they were before

Comment: i think the main problem si with org.apache.axis.tools.ant.wsdl.Wsdl2javaAntTask, as it is referencing a non-existing class. That class was part of axis-1.4.jar but no longer part of axis-1.6.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I found out that 'axis-tasks.properties' cannot be used with axis2-1.6.2.jar as it's no longer supported by that version, api has changed and i needed to write my own task defnitions to generate code from  WSDL.